# How to calculate the actual size of a .fit()-trained model in sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Is it possible to calculate the size of a model ( let's say a Random Forest classifier ) in scikit-learn?

For example:

> ```
>   from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
>   clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=-1, n_estimators=10000, min_samples_leaf=50)
>   clf.fit(self.X_train, self.y_train)
> ```

Can I determine the size of **`clf`**?

Comment: What do you mean by "the size of the model"?

Comment: For example, Amazon ML sets the limit of Model Size to be between 1 MB to 1GB.

Comment: `sys.getsizeof()` would return the size of only that object in memory. If there are references to other objects, it won't take into account the size of those objects, so there's a real risk of underestimating size. See [getsizeof documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html)

Comment: I did some testing, and it doesn't work. I have added more information to the question as well.

Comment: I have added the response.

Comment: I know this is old, but I think it is n_estimators * (2^max_depth-1) =  number of bytes.

Answer (score 18):

Along the same lines as Nijan's answer, you can also do it without having to save the model, using pickle:

```
import pickle
import sys

p = pickle.dumps(clf)
print(sys.getsizeof(p))
```

It will return the size in bytes.

Answer (score 1):

A way to do it is to dump the model in a file using joblib.dump and then calculate the file size.

Based on the previous example, you would use:

> joblib.dump(clf, fname) 
>   os.path.getsize(fname)

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough reputations points to comment what seems to be the admitted answer so sorry for the additional formal reply.

I tried the dronevil2 (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50149528/20093266) solution but here is my worry : the size of the pickle file is not the actual size of the model as it would be in production. "pickling" a python object writes it in a file in a binary format thus applying a compression method to it. To actually use the model we would need to "unpickel" it thus increasing it size..